# Automatically dealing with "disable dynamic updating"

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, automation

I'm programmatically creating notebooks containing dynamic content.  When a new notebook is being created, a window pops up:

[image]

I then manually click on "Continue" and it will create the notebook. The same steps happen for each notebook being created.  How to automatically deal with this?

Comment: Did you try to change `DynamicUpdating` and `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` in the option inspector?

Comment: No;  How to set `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` and `DynamicUpdating` as part of my program and resetting them to default right before the program is complete? I'd like to avoid using GUI.

Comment: Consider using queued/asynchronous evaluations for stuff that take too long and don't need priority

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can programatically change `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` like this:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "DynamicEvaluationTimeout" -> 30]
```

On my machine it was set to 6 by default.

Similary for `DynamicUpdating` where the options are True, False and Automatic

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "DynamicUpdating" -> True]
```

I think that just changing `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` to something high enough should fix your problem.